# Retrieve SFMC Data Extension Rows and Update 2nd Data Extension using SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs

I have created two Data Extensions. I am attempting to use a Script Activity to update Data Extension B based on the contents of Data Extension A. I have attempted to do so with SSJS retrieve request, because Data Extension A contains about 30,000 records.

The logic of the script seems to work. However, when I execute it inside of a Script Activity, in an Automation, the first 2500 rows are updated in Data Extension B, and then the Script seems to freeze doing nothing.

Is this an issue with SSJS in general or have I not properly formed my Request?

```
<script runat="server">

Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

var rr = Platform.Function.CreateObject("RetrieveRequest");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, 'ObjectType', 'DataExtensionObject[MyDeKey]');
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, 'Properties', 'ResultID');
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, 'Properties', 'EmailAddress');

do {

var results = [0,0];
var rows = Platform.Function.InvokeRetrieve(rr, results);
var status = results[0];
var requestId = results[1];

  if (rows != null) {
    for (var i in rows) {
      var resultID = rows[i].Properties[0].Value;
      var emailAddress = rows[i].Properties[1].Value;


       if (emailAddress != "") {
         var rows = Platform.Function.InsertDE("DestinationDE",["EmailBlank"],
                                                             [emailAddress]);
       } else {
         var rows = Platform.Function.InsertDE("DestionationDE",["EmailBlank"],
                                                             ["True"]);
      }
    }
  }
  rr.ContinueRequest = requestId;
} while(status === "MoreDataAvailable");

</script>
```

Comment: The max return is 2500. You will need to loop through it in 2500 increments to get the full return

Comment: @Gortonington I see. Thank you. I was thinking that the do...while would handle that based on the ContinueRequest. Do I need to add a further loop around that?

Comment: The retrieve is not in the do while which is why it's only pulling 2500

Comment: Can you include an answer and mark the question as solved? It really helps to know which questions have to be looked upon.